# Why wont Web.py let me run a server on port 80?

Tags: python, web.py

Im trying to create a website with Web.py but its not letting me open a create a socket on port 80 but it works on every other port.

I have port forwarded and all that so that's not the problem.

```
python main.py 80
```

but when I do this I get the error:

```
http://0.0.0.0:80/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 311, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
    return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/httpserver.py", line 148, in runsimple
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1753, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: No socket could be created
```

my code so far is:

```
import MySQLdb
import web
import hashlib as h


urls = (

'/', "index", "/register/?", "register", "/login/?", "login", "/thankyou/?", "thankyou"

)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render("templates/")
db = web.database (dbn="mysql", user="root", pw="461408", db="realmd")

class index():
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()
class register():
    def GET(self):
        return render.register()
    def POST(self):
        i = web.input()
        user = h.sha1(i.username).hexdigest()
        pw = h.sha1(i.password).hexdigest()

        n = db.insert("account", username=user, password=pw)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you have another service listening on port 80? Like apache?

Comment: "...it works on every other port." Really?

Comment: Have you tried port 81?  Maybe a permissions error.  On Linux (at least), you need to be root to listen on a low port like that.  (I think).

Comment: What operating system are you using? What other ports did you try?

Comment: So you tried on 65534 other ports?  ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You possibly have something else working on port 80.  Try the command `netstat -ln | grep 80` to check that.

Alternatively, you can try `telnet localhost 80`, and if the connection is refused then that port should be clear to use.

Answer (score 6):

I successfully start the service by using this command in port 80

```
sudo python index.py 80
```

but when I use the shortcut key （control+c） to close the service,there will be an error.

```
  ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 206, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 313, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
    return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/httpserver.py", line 159, in runsimple
    server.stop()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1932, in stop
    self.requests.stop(self.shutdown_timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/wsgiserver/__init__.py", line 1471, in stop
    worker.join(remaining_time)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 680, in join
    self.__block.release()
thread.error: release unlocked lock
^C^CException KeyboardInterrupt in <module 'threading' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

When it happens, I Kill All Python Processes...

```
killall -9 python
```

it's can solve the above problems, but not recommended

Answer (score 4):

Visit `127.0.0.1` in a browser.  There is likely already a process using port 80, and that port is supposed to be used for http, so that's probably the easiest way to see what's using it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on my RaspberryPi. To fix I just added sudo before the command. Try: sudo python main.py 80

Comment: Welcome to the site, Eddy. Your answer duplicates what has already been written above regarding permissions, though... the sudo syntax you provided approximately means 'run as if you were root'.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the fact you're trying to launch web.py as an unprivileged user?

try:

```
sudo python ./bin/blah.py
```